# Using sheet name inside a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make a formula where different sheets will be used, based on a value in a cell.
So my basic formula is =TRIM('5'!U103:U198). Here I get the information I want, from the sheet named: 5.

I have 31 sheets, named 1-31. Is there a way I can type the number of the sheet I want in a cell, and the formula automatically changes and I get the information from the sheet I want? I have tried to use the option INDIRECT > INDIRECT("'"&sheet&"'!"&name), but I can't get it working.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

By "name" in your attempted formula, you cannot mean "some valid cell, or range, address" because your formula would work in that case.

So my guess is that by "name" you mean a Named Range.

So, consider what you tell Excel to do. It seeks the `Refers to` value from the Named Range. That will ordinarily be something entered like `=A1:A2` and it is evaluated, and returned to whatever Excel is doing.

However, with `INDIRECT`, one needs to give it a STRING which will turn out to be a valid cell, or range, address. Something that it recognizes as such and can look for. But the usual thinking when defining a Named Range leads to `=A1:A2` which is not a string at all, but rather an actual range. Excel then looks where that range is and finds what's there, then presents THAT as a string to `INDIRECT`. This can lead to a simple #REF error, but if the string it gives to `INDIRECT` somehow does point to some valid string, one that can be interpreted as an address, the result could actually be a valid looking return that completely hides the fact it is failing abysmally.

So, what to do? It depends. First thing, for both basic situations, is you must make the `Refers to` entry for any Named Ranges you wish to use into a string. The most obvious way arises when you have an address there, like the `=A1:A2` one I mention above. Simply change that to a string:  `="a1:a2"` and you've got it. (Note I used lower case letters for it, as a way of catching someone's attention that what they are seeing is not a "real" address (because Excel would have capitalized the letters)... might help, can't hurt, so...)

However, what you have might be a formula meant to make the range (or cell) you seek "dynamic." In that case, you kinda have to keep a formula there... So in your cell formula here, you'd need to do more. You'd have to change the formula to generate a string out of the dynamically created range. That would be a bit complex to address with so many possible ways you might be creating that range, so I won't address it. (It would make a fine new question, but if you do that, be sure to include a full set of material. One missing piece and the answers won't do you any good.)

The other main way I wager you would encounter a problem though is the second issue I mentioned above. That would be that you have all that worked out, all is good, except you want to enter the Named Range name in a cell, not in the formula. If you have a real string in its definition, using it directly in the formula will work fine, but entering it in some cell (say a cell for the sheet name and a cell for one of any number of such ranges you define for each sheet) you find it does not.

The problem here can be fixed in the formula but only with a fair amount of effort. There is a simple thing you can do in the cell you enter the name in though:  just begin the entry with `=`. So, if the Named Range is `horse`, enter `=horse` instead of just typing `horse` on its own. All done, problem solved. Yes, it won't seem natural, as one would not usually need to enter the equal sign, but it is a small thing and for many, probably not too hard to get used to. After all, they ought to see an error if they forget, so can easily immediately remediate it. It's not like it'd get lost in evaluating results which are all wrong because... there'd be no results.

Answer (score 0):

You might need two helper cells. Let assume Cell D2 is the cell where you enter the sheet names, and D3 the cell where you will enter the range of the information to retrieve. Enter the following formula in for example E2:

```
=TRIM(INDIRECT(D2 & "!" & D3))
```

[image: Indirect formula result]